# How to import and use pubnub in angular2

Tags: angular, pubnub

I'm trying to use pubnub in my angular2 project. (**it's for realtime to get an order on browser**)

I used [pubnub-angular2](https://github.com/pubnub/pubnub-angular2)

I added and imported pubnub module in angular.module.
I guess I fellow pubnub guide, but it doesn't work at all, besides it makes an error that 'window' isn't defined.

Here is what I did to import pubnub.

1. npm install pubnub
2. npm install pubnub-angular2
3. providers: [ windows.PubNubAngular] in app.module

Also, it's my package.json.

```js
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ng serve",
    "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update",
    "e2e": "protractor"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~2.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~2.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "~2.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~2.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "~2.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "~3.0.0",
    "@types/moment-timezone": "^0.2.33",
    "angular-cli": "^1.0.0-beta.17",
    "angular2-jwt": "^0.1.25",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "bourbon": "^4.2.7",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "es6-promise": "^4.0.5",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "moment": "^2.17.1",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.10",
    "node-sass": "^3.13.0",
    "primeng": "^1.1.0",
    "pubnub-angular2": "^1.0.0-beta.6",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.23"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/hammerjs": "^2.0.33",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.2.30",
    "@types/moment": "^2.13.0",
    "@types/moment-timezone": "^0.2.33",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.42",
    "angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.17",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
    "codelyzer": "~0.0.26",
    "jasmine-core": "2.4.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
    "karma": "1.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.2.1",
    "protractor": "4.0.9",
    "ts-node": "1.2.1",
    "tslint": "3.13.0",
    "typescript": "2.0.2"
  }
}
```

It's app.module

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { DeliveryComponent } from './delivery/delivery.component';
import { AreaManagementComponent } from './area-management/area-management.component';
import { CountryComponent } from './area-management/country/country.component';

import { routing } from './app.routing';

import { AreaService } from "./area-management/area-management.service";
import { FDeliveryService } from "./f-delivery-setting/f-delivery.service";
import { ProvinceComponent } from './area-management/province/province.component';
import { SigninComponent } from './signin/signin.component';
import { CityComponent } from './area-management/city/city.component';
import { AreaComponent } from './area-management/area/area.component';
import { DeliveryAreaComponent } from './area-management/delivery-area/delivery-area.component';
import { FDeliverySettingComponent } from './f-delivery-setting/f-delivery-setting.component';
import { TermsComponent } from './terms/terms.component';
import { TermsListComponent } from './terms-list/terms-list.component';
import { TermsListService } from "./terms-list/terms-list.service";
import { TermsService } from "./terms/terms.service";
import { UserManagementComponent } from './user-management/user-management.component';
import { UserService} from "./user-management/user.service";
import { NavComponent } from './nav/nav.component';

import { MaterialModule } from '@angular/material';
import 'hammerjs';

import {
  DialogModule,
  ButtonModule,
  DataTableModule,
  InputTextModule,
  TabViewModule,
  DropdownModule,
  EditorModule,
  SharedModule,
  AutoCompleteModule,
  PanelMenuModule,
  MenuModule,
  ContextMenuModule,
  PasswordModule,
  FileUploadModule,
  InputTextareaModule,
  RadioButtonModule,
  CalendarModule,
  CheckboxModule,
  ConfirmDialogModule,
  ConfirmationService, InputMaskModule
} from "primeng/primeng";
import { SignupComponent } from './signin/signup.component';
import { LicenseComponent } from './license/license.component';
import { TermsShowComponent } from './terms-show/terms-show.component';
import { AuthGuardService } from "./signin/auth-guard.service";
import { AuthService } from "./signin/auth.service";
import { UserDetailComponent } from './user-detail/user-detail.component';
import { LicenseDetailComponent } from './license/license-detail/license-detail.component';
import { UserDetailService } from "./user-detail/user-detail.service";
import { LicenseService } from "./license/license.service";
import { BranchManagementComponent } from './branch-management/branch-management.component';
import { BranchService } from "./branch-management/branch.service";
import { BranchDetailComponent } from './branch-management/branch-detail/branch-detail.component';
import { InternalComponent } from './home/internal/internal.component';
import { ExternalComponent } from './home/external/external.component';
import { ClassificationComponent } from './classification/classification.component';
import { ClientComponent } from './client/client.component';
import { DmBillingComponent } from './payment-billing/dm-billing/dm-billing.component';
import { PartnerBillingComponent } from './payment-billing/partner-billing/partner-billing.component';
import { WowbillingComponent } from './payment-billing/wowbilling/wowbilling.component';
import { DailyReportingComponent } from './daily-reporting/daily-reporting.component';
import { AccountClosingComponent } from './account-closing/account-closing.component';
import { AccountingComponent } from "./accounting-balance/accounting-balance.component";
import { DeliveryService } from "./delivery/delivery.service";
import { UserAddComponent } from './user-add/user-add.component';
import { NavService } from "./nav/nav.service";
import { PartnerService } from "./shared/partner.service";
import { ClientService } from "./shared/client.service";
import { PartnerComponent } from './partner/partner.component';
import { PartnerDetailComponent } from './partner/partner-detail/partner-detail.component';
import { NewBranchComponent } from './branch-management/new-branch/new-branch.component';
import { ForgetPasswordComponent } from './signin/forget-password/forget-password.component';
import { DeliveryDetailComponent } from './delivery/delivery-detail/delivery-detail.component';
import {FileUploadService} from "./shared/file-upload.service";
import { PartnerEditComponent } from './partner/partner-edit/partner-edit.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    DeliveryComponent,
    AreaManagementComponent,
    CountryComponent,
    ProvinceComponent,
    SigninComponent,
    CityComponent,
    AreaComponent,
    DeliveryAreaComponent,
    FDeliverySettingComponent,
    TermsComponent,
    TermsListComponent,
    UserManagementComponent,
    NavComponent,
    SignupComponent,
    LicenseComponent,
    TermsShowComponent,
    UserDetailComponent,
    LicenseDetailComponent,
    BranchManagementComponent,
    BranchDetailComponent,
    InternalComponent,
    ExternalComponent,
    AccountingComponent,
    ClassificationComponent,
    ClientComponent,
    DmBillingComponent,
    PartnerBillingComponent,
    WowbillingComponent,
    DailyReportingComponent,
    AccountClosingComponent,
    UserAddComponent,
    PartnerComponent,
    PartnerDetailComponent,
    NewBranchComponent,
    ForgetPasswordComponent,
    DeliveryDetailComponent,
    PartnerEditComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    routing,
    MaterialModule.forRoot(),
    ReactiveFormsModule,

    //primeNG
    InputTextareaModule,
    InputTextModule,
    DataTableModule,
    DialogModule,
    DropdownModule,
    ButtonModule,
    TabViewModule,
    EditorModule,
    SharedModule,
    PanelMenuModule,
    MenuModule,
    ContextMenuModule,
    PasswordModule,
    FileUploadModule,
    RadioButtonModule,
    CalendarModule,
    CheckboxModule,
    ConfirmDialogModule,
    InputMaskModule
  ],
  providers: [
    AreaService,
    FDeliveryService,
    TermsListService,
    TermsService,
    UserService,
    AuthGuardService,
    AuthService,
    UserDetailService,
    LicenseService,
    BranchService,
    DeliveryService,
    NavService,
    PartnerService,
    ClientService,
    ConfirmationService,
    FileUploadService,
    
    window.PubNubAngular
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And it makes errors. I have a problem to import pubnub, so I don't have any code about this. What I did to import added `windows.PubNubAngular` only to `providers` in app.module.

```
Uncaught Error: Invalid provider for the NgModule 'AppModule' - only instances of Provider and Type are allowed
```

[image]

If you know how to import and use pubnub in angular2, please give little advice.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You might want to share some details about your code. Also, what environment are you trying to run this in? A browser? Something else?

Comment: Yes, please share you code.

Comment: I'm sorry I add detail right now

Comment: @TedHopp, I edited, if you let me know how to solve this problem, I really appreciate about it. Thank you

Comment: @CraigConover, I added more detail, check it out please

Comment: Please post the contents of app.module.ts.

Comment: Thank you for the reply :)
I add it

Comment: @CraigConover Can you give a little help?

Comment: See answer below from PubNub engineer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version used is not compatible with typescript the newone is already compatible, you have to pull down again and follow the last documentation.

Comment: Do you mean `pubnub-angular2@1.0.0-beta7`?

Comment: This new version is compatible with TS